# Android SDK N/A not found React Native in MacOS

Tags: android, react-native

I have installed Android Studio on my mac Apple M2. I also install all packages and set PATH to .zshrc like this:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
```

I tried to echo $PATH and it works. but I tested with `npx react-native doctor' it show an error:

```
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: Not Found
```

I can't fix this issue.
Do you know how to fix this issue?

Here is some information:

```
Apple Chip M2 ARM
Node: V18
NPX, NPM: 9.6.7
Android Studio (Android SDK 34)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same issue on M2 Chip

Answer (score 1):

While it feels like there should be a more elegant solution here's what helped me.

I had the same issue on an Intel MBP after following official React documentation (Adb simulator was marked as uninstalled as well), hope it helps!

To run my app I:

1. Launched Android Studio under **superuser** (that can be done by logging with `sudo su` and then `sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`)
2. Opened `android` folder in it, waited for it to build (SDK 33.0.0 and all requirements were met under my regular user so it automatically obtained those)
3. Under my regular user ran `sudo npm run android` in the project's home folder - that automatically launched the simulator and started installing the app on it